# HTTP HEAD request /error triggers automatically for a spring boot application with health check configured

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, readinessprobe, livenessprobe, actuator

I am having a spring boot application sample-microservice. My MS is deployed on OCP server, and also has health check configured with readiness and liveness probes.
So, once the application starts up, I get below logs:

```
{"@timestamp":"timestamp","level":"INFO","application-name":"sample-microservice",...,"message":"REST CONTROLLER RESPONSE ==> GET | 200 OK | http://1.2.3.4:8080/actuator/health"}
```

which is fine.

But in between these, I also observe some logs like:

```
{"@timestamp":"timestamp","level":"INFO","application-name":"sample-microservice",...,"message":"REST CONTROLLER RESPONSE ==> HEAD | 404 NOT_FOUND | https://sample-microservice-hostname/error"}
```

I'm not able to understand why these are getting logged in the console. And does this mean my MS is unavailable, or maybe down, for that small instant of time ?

Thank you in advance for any explanations.